# IOError:[Error 13]: Permission denide: 'c:\\users\\ravikumar.mevada\\anaconda2\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32\\win32api.pyd'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, spyder, psychopy

I am using python 2.7, 32 bit on windows 10, 64 bit. Whenever I try to install psychopy module by doing `pip install psychopy`, I am getting below mentioned error. I am not able to understand what is the problem. I have also made changes in environmental variable to set anconda bin and anaconda scripts as highest priority.  I am running same program for last 8 months and never got any kind of problem. I am trying to install everything in new PC and getting this kind of error in my old and new PC. How can fix this problem?

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\ravikumar.mevada\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "c:\users\ravikumar.mevada\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "c:\users\ravikumar.mevada\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
File "c:\users\ravikumar.mevada\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
File "c:\users\ravikumar.mevada\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
File "c:\users\ravikumar.mevada\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "c:\users\ravikumar.mevada\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
File "c:\users\ravikumar.mevada\anaconda2\lib\shutil.py", line 97, in copyfile
with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\users\\ravikumar.mevada\\anaconda2\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32\\win32api.pyd'
```

Comment: The actual question is: How did you install Anaconda in the first place? If you installed it as a user, the permissions should allow you to install packages as a user, too. Did you maybe run the installation script as an administrator? That’s most probably NOT what you want. I suggest you uninstall Anaconda and try re-installing as a user, without escalating privileges during the installation procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your user doesn't have the permission to install packages in your system (for all users). Here's how to fix this problem:

- From the Command Prompt, you can **install the package for your user only**, like this:

  ```
  pip install <package> --user
  ```

***OR***

- You can **install the package as Administrator**, by following these steps:

  1. Run the Command Prompt as Administrator, using the `Run This Program As An Administrator` option.
  2. Run the command `pip install <package>`

Answer (score 0):

open your command prompt by right click -> open as administrator   after that

type:

```
   py -2.7 -m pip help 
   py -2.7 -m pip install psychopy
            OR
   conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html